# adorner and drawing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm implementing a UI using grid to show, drag/drop objects using [adorner class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adorner.aspx). now, is it possible to draw some geometric shapes using mouse? e.g. drawing a straight line from point a to point b

Thanks.

Comment: You can just check the Position at MouseDown, and the position at MouseUp, and draw the new Line ?

Comment: Consider it done. Now, question is that this line is an object or it is a regular line we draw in paint or photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a line at run-time
/// </summary>
public void CreateALine()
{
   // Create a Line
   Line redLine = new Line();
   redLine.X1 = 50;
   redLine.Y1 = 50;
   redLine.X2 = 200;
   redLine.Y2 = 200;

   // Create a red Brush
   SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
   redBrush.Color = Colors.Red;

   // Set Line's width and color
   redLine.StrokeThickness = 4;
   redLine.Stroke = redBrush;

   // Add line to the Grid.
   LayoutRoot.Children.Add(redLine);
}
```

Taken from [c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/line-in-wpf/)